# Configuring Postfix to not use a daemon

Tags: linux, postfix

I realize this is wildly offtopic but this is my last hope. I would like to only send mail from my computer, both locally and to remote servers, so I don't think I need postfix to run a daemon, but I can't find anything that will tell me how to configure it. Would anyone happen to know?

Comment: Can you explain why you do not want to run it as a daemon? It would help pick the correct answer.

Comment: "Why you do not want to run it as a daemon?" What about when you want to run it as a Docker process which doesnt quit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally it's still useful to have an SMTP server running as a daemon - just make sure it only listens on the loopback (127.0.0.1) interface so that it doesn't accept mail from the outside world.

By running as a daemon, your Postfix installation can continue to manage your outgoing mail queue optimally (for those instances where an outgoing e-mail couldn't be delivered immediately).

Also, some software prefers to make a direct SMTP connection to port 25 on a machine somewhere rather than invoking `/usr/sbin/sendmail` and piping the mail to that program.  Running as a daemon is then preferable to having your SMTP service started on demand via `inetd`.

Comment: Hmm, so you'd advise me to use the default setup? My machine only has an Atom processor and I don't want to bog it down with unused daemons, would postfix consume many resources running?

Comment: no, when it's not being used it should use negligible resources.  Mostly it'll use RAM in any case, not CPU.

Comment: If you've got a netbook or something with an Atom, you've probably got at least two or three orders of magnitude more memory than Postfix will use.  Don't worry about it.

Comment: FYI, I had Postfix running on a 486 with 16MB of RAM at one point and it only used a small fraction of that, just a few hundered K.

Answer (score 2):

Just comment out the line starting with 'smtp' in /etc/postfix/master.cf.

Answer (score 0):

You may stop postfix service and remove it from startup services.

If you are using redhat you may use

```
chkconfig --level 2,3,4,5 postfix off
```